# How can I get more info in the dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, info

When searching for the phrase 'invoices' in the Ubuntu dash, I get a few different folders that all relate to different projects. However, there is no way of seeing which is which, as I cannot see the folder location... if there was just some simple info saying its parent folder, or more detailed location, the dash would be perfect. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I would try searching for something that is more specific instead.

Comment: I don't want to search for something more specific - i want to search for 'invoices', which is in the folder 'job number 1'. All the information I would need is a simple bit of path text displaying below the icon in the dash e.g. "Desktop/work/job number 1/invoices". This would help choose the right one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu 12.10, you can right-click items in the dash to reveal more info about that item.

Comment: Right-clicking doesn't give much information for folders I must say.

Comment: maybe the locate command in the terminal?